# Pause Python script running Paramiko in SSH shell between commands to allow full dump

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm struggling with writing full results from commands before the next command writes over it (at least this is what I suspect is happening).

I've written a Python script to uses Paramiko to SSH into a Cisco switch and execute a list of commands from a seed list, named "cmdlist.txt".

START SCRIPT

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
TERM_WIDTH = 'terminal width 250\n'
TERM_LENGTH = 'terminal length 0\n'
chan.send(TERM_WIDTH)
time.sleep(1)
chan.send(TERM_LENGTH)
time.sleep(1)

with open('cmdlist.txt') as CMDLIST:
  for CMD in CMDLIST:
      COMMAND = '{}\n'.format(CMD)
      chan.send(COMMAND)
      time.sleep(30)
      COMMAND_Ret = chan.recv(9999)
      COMMAND_Ret = COMMAND_Ret.decode('utf8')
      COMMAND_Ret = StripLastLine(COMMAND_Ret)
      if set ('^').intersection(COMMAND_Ret):
           COMMAND = COMMAND.rstrip()
           FAILURE = '\nCOMMAND {} FAILED.\n\n\n'.format(COMMAND)
           RESULTS.write(FAILURE)
      else:
           COMMAND = COMMAND.rstrip()
           RESULTS.write(COMMAND_Ret)
```

STOP SCRIPT

I've played with the "time.sleep()" delay but it doesn't prevent long commands from writing over the previous command.

Is there a method to have the script pause for the length of time it takes for a command to complete then continue when the script has completed writing everything?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the paramiko API, but if you are on a unix machine (or windows with cygwin), have you considered using `subprocess.check_call` to execute the ssh command?  You may find it useful to know about the -t switch.

Comment: In fact, if you go that way, I recommend using something like `child = subprocess.Popen(["sh", "-c", shell_command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` then `child.communicate()` to fetch output.

Comment: I also notice you seem to read CMD with trailing newline (if present - last line in file may lack it), then append a second newline, looks wrong?